# how to add common statements to all the implementations of an interface?

Tags: java

I have a code in this current form.

```
public interface Converter {
    void convert();
}

public class X implements Converter{
   public void convert(){
      System.out.println("X conversion");
  }
}

public class Y implements Converter{
   public void convert(){
      System.out.println("Y conversion");
  }
}
```

Now I need to add common steps in all the implementations of `convert()` method. Like `System.out.println("common steps")` to all the implemenations of `convert()` method. What is the best way to do

Comment: You can create default method in your `Converter` interface.

Comment: And like this common logic won't be in all implementations, but has to be called specifically every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to achieve it:

1. Make abstract class implementing `Converter`, with its' implementation of `convert()` holding common logic
2. Add abstract method, which will hold logic specific for concrete implementers, `X` and `Y` in your case
3. Call abstract method in `convert()`
4. Make `X` and `Y` extend abstract class
5. Implement specific logic

**Edit:** Adding example code to illustrate it.

Abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public void convert() {
        System.out.println("common steps");
        this.specificSteps();
    }

    protected abstract void specificSteps();
}
```

Implementation of `convert()` consists of common part - `System.out.println("common steps");`, and specific part - `this.specificSteps();`. Abstract method `specificSteps()` forces every subclass to add its' own specific conversion.

`X` and `Y`:

```
public class X extends BaseConverter {

    @Override
    protected void specificSteps() {
        System.out.println("X conversion");
    }
}
```

```
public class Y extends BaseConverter {

    @Override
    protected void specificSteps() {
        System.out.println("Y conversion");
    }
}
```

Like this you only write the specific logic in concrete classes, they inherit common logic from `BaseConverter`.

Lastly, simple main to test.

```
public class TempMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Converter> converters = new ArrayList<>();
        converters.add(new X());
        converters.add(new Y());
        for (Converter converter : converters) {
            converter.convert();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using default method of interface. Default method in interface must have function body. You can use it this way.

```
public interface Converter {
    default void convert(){
      System.out.println("common steps");
    }
}

public class X implements Converter{
   public void convert(){
      Converter.super.convert();
  }
}

public class Y implements Converter{
   public void convert(){
      Converter.super.convert();
  }
}
```

Comment: `Converter.super.convert();` has to be called in every implementation. Your answer does not add common logic in all implementations.

Comment: This is the way Java supports Multiple Inheritance through Interface (of course JDK 1.8 onward).

Comment: This is not the way, at least for this question. You have to call `Converter.super.convert();` in `X` and `Y`, and when you create classes `A`, `B`, `C` and so on implementing `Converter`, you have to call `Converter.super.convert();` in them as well. OP wants to add common logic in **all** implementations. Also question has no relation to multiple inheritance.

Comment: The point of `default` method is that you can use `public class X implements Converter{}` and `new X().convert()` will work without declaring `convert()` again.